# Rails 3 - associations - how it work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, model, associations

I try to understand the behavior of associations, but I am doing something wrong.

I have these two models:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
end
```

This means that one album could have many photos and every photo belongs to one album.

Now, if I have this code in the view (assuming I have set `@album = 106` in the controller, which is the ID number of the album):

```
@album.photos.each_with_index do |pic, index|
  ...
end
```

And I got the error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'photos' for 106:Fixnum):`

Why do I get this error message? I thought I have to set the `@album` variable ID of album and then the loop will be searching the photos in the table `Photos` by `album_id` (album_id=106).

What I am doing still wrong?

Comment: Using a partial to render each photo is preferred, since this separates the 'building blocks' of your views. render @album.photos will render the 'photos/_photo.html.erb' view once for every photo in the album.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the model instance to fetch the associations, like this:

```
@album = Album.find(106)
```

To sort the photos by creation date, do it like this:

```
@album.photos.order('created_at DESC').each_with_index do |pic, index|
  ...
end
```

Comment: yeah, it's right, thank you. I would like to ask you for one question yet - now it works and I'm finally getting the data from the table `Photos` - is possible to set `each` loop, what the way to select data from the table? Eg., the implicit way by lowest ID, but I would need by the newest time... is it possible this statement?

Comment: I like RoR each day more and more! Thank you Benoit.